# Laravel Backpack store image

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to store an image using Backpack's CRUD.
The Model's name is ProductModel, and in the SetupCreateOperation, I have:

```php
CRUD::addField([
     'name' => 'photo',
     'label' => 'Foto',
     'type'  => 'image'
]);
```

When I try to upload an image, I get an error saying the following.

> String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'photo.'

Indeed the string being passed is almost 7000 characters long.

**Model**

```php
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SoldProduct', 
            'product_model_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Migration**

```php
Schema::create('product_models', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('photo'); //path 
    $table->integer('stock');
    $table->integer('limited_edition_pieces');
    $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
    $table->string('note')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

What should I do?

Comment: Don't save an image to database, save just path or folder path from your images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set Image you need to add Field like this

```
 $this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'image',
    'label' => 'Image',
    'type' => 'upload',
    'upload' => true
]);
```

use `'disk' => 'uploads'` if you want to upload to s3(amazon), otherwise don't add it if you want to keep images in public folder.

Also keep in mind that your image attribute needs to be set in your model.
Like this,

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "image";
        // you can check here if file is recieved or not using hasFile()
        $disk = "public";
        $destination_path = "/uploads";       
        $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
    }
```

The `uploadFileToDisk()` lies in your `Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait` which you have already added

Comment: Wow, thanks, this really helped. Now everything works.

Comment: do that but in image path show "/tmp/phphdc0Yq" and not move file to public folder